# Picasa Web Service in android

Tags: android, api, picasa

Is it possible to get Picasa Album photos using gdata API ( Google Data API)

my imports :

```
   "import com.google.gdata.client.photos.PicasawebService;
    import com.google.gdata.data.photos.AlbumFeed;
    import com.google.gdata.data.photos.PhotoEntry;"
```

my service creation :

```
PicasawebService service = new PicasawebService("exampleClient");
```

If I use that in my Android activity it compiles fine when I run the app I get no class found excetion. Any Help will be greatly appreciated

```
    09-29 01:01:41.160: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(30113): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.gdata.client.photos.PicasawebService
    09-29 01:01:41.160: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(30113):     at com.chandu.examples.picassa.PicassaAlbumsActivity.loadAlbum(PicassaAlbumsActivity.java:48)
    09-29 01:01:41.160: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(30113):     at com.chandu.examples.picassa.PicassaAlbumsActivity.onCreate(PicassaAlbumsActivity.java:31)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your GData client JAR should be be in the `war/WEB-INF/lib` directory

> From the documentation:

To use this library in your App Engine application, you must first copy the JARs listed below from the lib directory of the gdata-java-client package to your project's `war/WEB-INF/lib` directory:

```
gdata-client-1.0.jar
gdata-client-meta-1.0.jar
gdata-core-1.0.jar
gdata-docs-3.0.jar
gdata-docs-meta-3.0.jar
gdata-media-1.0.jar
```

Comment: I am trying to use this in an Android app. A standalone Java program works fine. I am not running my own web app but trying to connect to PicasaAlbums using gdata API

Comment: Any luck Chandu? I have the same issue?

Comment: Any luck with picassa api on android??